# Customizing organizing imports in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Is there any way of customizing how in Visual Studio Code the command `ctrl + shift + p` -> `Organize imports` formats javascript code?

Comment: You're using a plugin to do this. It's not default vscode behavior. Check the documentation of your plugin.

Comment: It's a build in plugin.